# Turnbased multiplayer app both players cant take a turn

Tags: android, google-play-services

When you click **Play!** on my chess app, it takes you to the select players screen like so...

NOTE: mGamesClient is a `GameClient` that has been connected using `mGamesClient.connect()`.

```
Intent intent = mGamesClient.getSelectPlayersIntent(1, 1, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SELECT_PLAYERS);
```

Now after I select my player (only one player because it's chess) I get the `onActivityResult` callback, which looks like this...

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);

        if (request == RC_SELECT_PLAYERS) {
            if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // user canceled
                return;
            }

            // get the invitee list
            final ArrayList<String> invitees = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(GamesClient.EXTRA_PLAYERS);

            // get auto-match criteria
            Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;
            int minAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(
                    GamesClient.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
            int maxAutoMatchPlayers = data.getIntExtra(
                    GamesClient.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
            if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
                autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                        minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
            } else {
                autoMatchCriteria = null;
            }
            TurnBasedMatchConfig tbmc = TurnBasedMatchConfig.builder()
                    .addInvitedPlayers(invitees)
                    .setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria).build();

            // kick the match off
            mGamesClient.createTurnBasedMatch(this, tbmc);
        }

        Log.v("LOG", "+++ ONACTIVITYRESULT HOMESCREENACTIVITY +++");
    }
```

Now because `mGamesClient.createTurnBasedMatch(this, tbmc);` gets called, I get a `onTurnBasedMatchInitiated` callback, which looks like this...

```
@Override
    public void onTurnBasedMatchInitiated(int statusCode, TurnBasedMatch match) {
        Log.v("LOG", "+++ ONTURNBASEDMATCHINITIATED HOMESCREENACTIVITY +++");
        mMatch = match;
        // Check if the status code is not success;
        if (statusCode != GamesClient.STATUS_OK) {
            showErrorMessage(statusCode);
            Log.v("LOG", "" + statusCode);
            return;
        }

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OfflineInGameActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("soundOn", soundOn);
            i.putExtra("LoLImages", LoLImages);
            startActivity(i);
            return;
    }
```

And now my chess activity starts. On my opponents side, he/she recieves an invitation which, if accepted, will call `acceptTurnBasedInvitation`.

Now my problem is, neither of the players can make a move, for each player it says its not their turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

[Deciding who is player one and two in a round based game with Google Play Game Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135519/deciding-who-is-player-one-and-two-in-a-round-based-game-with-google-play-game-s)

Here is the relevant section from the google documentation :

https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer#taking_the_first_turn

Comment: I don't need this anymore, I already fixed it and have published the app. But thanks for the answer, I'm sure it would have helped me solve it :)